# Django vs Spring framework

Tags: software-development, django

My friend and I are starting a company of our own, where we develop software products that offers services to other companies and institutes.

We are in the phase of deciding what technologies and frameworks to use. For the back-end we are trying to choose between Django and Spring. Here is what we have come to:

***Spring***

**Pros:**

Simplified & version conflict free dependency management through the starter POMs.

You can just assemble the jar artifact which comes with an embedded Tomact, Jetty or Undertow application server and you are ready to go.

Offers better support for micro-services.

**Cons:**

Spring boot may unnecessarily increase the deployment binary size with unused dependencies.

spring Boot applications can range in size from 50 MB – 250 MB, if not larger. (99% is dependency JARs)

Spring promotes Dependency Injection (DI). But if you start using Spring, your project becomes dependent on Spring framework. This is a dependency that you are creating for your project. You may not be able to come out of it in the future.

***Django***

**Pros:**

Easier and faster deployment.

Smaller in size

More secure

Ability to integrate things like machine learning

**Cons:**

Not good with micro-services,  Django really shines in an environment in which you can make use of all the included “batteries”, Django ORM + Admin + Generic Views.

Tightly coupled

can you offer more suggestions and provide feed back ?

Thank you.